# How to correctly parameterize non-static method with upper bound?

Tags: java, generics

I need to write parameterized method that would return collection of type `T`, where `T` can be object of any class that inherits `I`. It's trivial if `T` is defined on class level, but I need generic non-static method. Can't understand compiler, anything below seems logical to me.

```
public class Foo {

    public <T extends I> Collection<T> test(Class<T> clazz) {
        List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new B());
        return list; // compilation error: required type Collection<T>
                     //                    provided List<B>
    }

    interface I {}

    interface A extends I {}

    class B implements A {}
}
```

Comment: *Bad naming:* Having types (classes, interfaces, ...) with one-letter names makes them look like type parameters, which by convention are one-letter names specifically to separate them from regular type names. Please use better names, e.g. for demo code, you can use names like `Foo`, `Bar`, `MyInterface`, `MyClass`, `ClassA`, `EnumB`, etc.

Comment: One-letter names is perfectly valid and demo is only a few lines long.

Comment: Since `T` is only constrained to implement `I`, there is no guarantee that `T` is assignment-compatible with `B`, e.g. is could be a `C` class that also implements `I`. Re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the compiler that's confusing you, it's the concepts themselves.

Let's make this very pragmatic: We have a class type hierarchy: Apple and Pear both extend Fruit, and Fruit extends Object.

Here's the key realization:

**A `List<Apple>` cannot just be treated as a `List<Fruit>`**.

Imagine you could do that:

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
List<Fruit> fruits = apples; // This is not legal
fruits.add(new Pear());
Apple apple = apples.get(0); // but apples.get(0) is.. a pear???
```

That's why you can't do that. The difference is: You can 'write' apples and pears INTO a collection.

If you want to learn all about it, it's called 'variance'. Something like `Fruit fruit = new Apple();` is covariance in action (the type itself and any subtype thereof is fine). But generics is invariant, because it has to be, see above example. There's even contravariance, where a type or any **supertype** thereof is fine. In generics you have to explicitly choose variance:

```
List<? extends Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Apple>(); // covariance
List<? super Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Fruit>(); // contravariance
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>(); // invariance (Default)
```

When you have a 'covariant fruits' list, you **cannot add anything to it. At all***.

When you have a 'contravariant fruits' list, you can add just fine, but you cannot get anything from it. Or rather, whenever you get results out, their type is just `Object`, that works only because everything is guaranteed to be an Object.

With an 'invariant fruits' list, you can add **and** get just fine.

Change your code to read: `public <T extends I> Collection<? extends T> test(...` and it'll work. But `test(B.class).add(new B());` wouldn't. You can't have both work, because fundamentally that cannot work.

*) Except literally `null` because its every type. Irrelevant for the general principle of variance.